# Python script won't run through php when using files

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run this python script using `$output=shell_exec('python /var/www/names.py');` in my php code. It will print the first foo however it won't do anymore than that.

```
print("foo")

f = open("colo.txt", "w")


f.write("foo")
f.write("foo")

f.write("foo")
f.write("foo")


print("foo1")

f.close()
```

If I comment out all of the file parts like so

```
print("foo")

#f = open("colo.txt", "w")


#f.write("foo")
#f.write("foo")

#f.write("foo")
#f.write("foo")


print("foo1")

#f.close()
```

It will print both foo and foo1. Also if I run the .py file it will work on both my desktop and my PI without having to comment out those parts.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('python /var/www/names.py');
echo "$output";
?>
```

I am running PHP version 5.4.4, python 3.2, on a raspberry pi. I am at a complete loss at why this is happening.

Comment: The code works fine. Try removing the extra (blank) lines perhaps.

Comment: @l'L'l I get the same result

Comment: Is foo being written to colo.txt?

Comment: @l'L'l It will write it if I run just the .py script however it won't if I run it through the php file

Comment: Okay, so it seems to be an issue with `PHP`. I wonder if it's permissions related. Another thing you could try is instead of using `shell_exec` try using `passthru`

Comment: @l'L'l It turned out to be a permissions issue! Thank you so very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I try to run all your script on my desktop, using : Windows 8, XAMPP, Firefox, and all runs well.
Do you have privilege to create or modify in that folder ?

Comment: You were right! It didn't have permissions to write there! Thank you so much!